# How to create pop up box in PHP laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

i created one view.blade.php page. There in table added column action, inside that given to button, Delete and View/Edit. When i click on View/Edit button one form page should come as pop up box. For that how can i write javascript. I am a beginner in laravel. So can any one please help me out?
My view.blade page is given is given below

userAdmin.blade.php

```
 @extends('app')

@section('content')


    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
            <li class="active">user information</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="templatemo-content">

            <h1>View/Edit user information</h1>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" bgcolor="#fff8dc">
                            <h3>Select User :</h3>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User ID</th>
                                <th>User Desc</th>
                                <th>Contact Name</th>
                                <th>Contact Email</th>
                                <th>Time Zone</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                                <th>Last Login (GMT+05:30)</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            {{--{{ UserController::getIndex() }}--}}
                            @foreach($name as $nam)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->userID }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->description }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->contactName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->contactPhone }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->timeZone }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if($nam->isActive == '1')
                                            Yes
                                            @else
                                        No
                                            @endif
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($nam->lastLoginTime)) }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{--@if ( in_array($nam->isActive, array('Yes','No')) )--}}

                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    {{--@if ($nam->isActive == 'Yes')--}}
                                                        <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-bookingid="{{ $nam->userID }}"><a href="#">View/ Edit</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    {{--@endif--}}
                                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/user/delete/'.$nam->userID)}}">Delete</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        {{--@endif--}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{$name->links()}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </br>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>
@endsection
```

and the form page i need to pop up is

```
 @extends('app')

@section('content')

    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">View/Edit User</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading">View/Edit User Information</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('accountAdmin') }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="{{ old('userID')}}" placeholder="Enter User ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Active</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('isActive') }}" name="isActive" >
                                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" placeholder="Enter the description">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactName" value="{{ old('contactName') }}" placeholder="Enter Contact Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactPhone" value="{{ old('contactPhone') }}" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" value="{{ old('contactEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Notify Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="{{ old('notifyEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Time Zone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('timeZone') }}" name="timeZone" >
                                            <option value="0">GMT+05:30</option>
                                            <option value="Inactive">xyz</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Authorized Group</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('distanceUnits') }}" name="distanceUnits" >
                                            <option value="0">all</option>
                                            <option value="1">Km</option>
                                            <option value="2">Nm</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Login page</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('firstLoginPageID') }}" name="firstLoginPageID" >
                                            <option value="0">Main Menu</option>
                                            <option value="1">Liter</option>
                                            <option value="2">IG</option>
                                            <option value="3">ft^3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Maximum Access Level</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('maxAccessLevel') }}" name="maxAccessLevel" >
                                            <option value="3">New/Delete</option>
                                            <option value="1">Read/View</option>
                                            <option value="2">Write/Edit</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                            Save
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

userController page is

```
    class UserController extends Controller
{
    public $type = 'User';

    public function getIndex()
    {

        $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);
    }

    public function getData()
    {

        $name = DB::table('user');
        return view('user.add')->with('name', $name);
    }

    public function userInsert()
    {
        $postUser = Input::all();
        //insert data into mysql table
        $data =      array('userID'=> $postUser['userID']
        );
        //  echo print_r($data);
        $ck = 0;
        $ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);
        //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
        $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);


    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        DB::table('user')->where('userID', '=', $id)->delete();
        return redirect('userAdmin');
    }
}
```

routes.php is

```
    Route::any('userAdmin', 'UserController@getIndex');
Route::any('user/add', 'UserController@getData');
Route::any('user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
Route::post('userAdmin', 'UserController@userInsert');
```

Anyone please tell me how to write js code for that

Comment: You may want to look at using modals to achieve this (I see you have begun incorporating them with your code, but the modal content is missing on the page). These are pop up windows that can be triggered when a linked button (or anything) is clicked. You essentially want to put your form inside the modal body and have that modal open on click

Comment: sorry i didn get u?. Model means inside the model page?. (user.php)

Comment: he means "modAl" and not "modEl". What you are searching for has nothing to do with PHP, it's Frontend part. You should create a modal with corresponding ID you are calling for: `<div id="acceptModal">This is your modal</div>`